# Powershell Renaming with sequential numeric suffixes

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting

I need some assistance with the below renaming script. I'm trying to rename the below files by adding RAW at the end and with incrementing numbers

Original file names:

```
AFC17073199C
AFC17080199C
AFC17080299C
```

File after renaming should be:

```
AFC17073199CRAW.101
AFC17080199CRAW.102
AFC17080299CRAW.103
```

Script Used:

```
cd D:/TempKIG/F.kig_TEMP/E.kig_FILES/F.kig_0829460180

ls

$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*99C'
$global:i = 0; Get-Random $files -Count $files.Count | 
 Rename-Item -NewName { "$files"+'RAW.{0:100}' -f ++$global:i}

SET resexe=0
```

Comment: Please include a description of the problem your facing, any error messages you encounter and an actual _question_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you need to loop over the files. Either with `ForEach` or `ForEach-Object`. Then you can pipe the individual files to be renamed into `Rename-Item`

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem D:/TempKIG/F.kig_TEMP/E.kig_FILES/F.kig_0829460180 -File -Filter '*99C' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { "$($_.basename)RAW.{0:100}" -f $i}
        $i++
    }
```

Also no need to put the `$i` into the global scope. If you want to randomize the  order you can pipe `Get-ChildItem` into `Sort-Object {Get-Random}` before piping into the `ForEach-Object`.

If you are running PowerShell on Windows, `SET resexe=0` probably isn't doing what you want it to do. This sets the variable `${resexe=0} = $null`. If you want to use `Set` (which is an alias to `Set-Variable`) you probably would want to use `set resexe 0`. But `$resexe = 0` is much more succinct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help BenH. The files are being renamed correctly. But i am have the issue to increase the sequence. It being renamed with .101  for all files. How can we fix this?

Comment: @TusvinIyadoo That's what I get for only testing on an array of one file. I updated my answer to separate the increment into another statement.

Comment: @TusvinIyadoo If an answer works for you, it's best practice to accept it.